# Eloquent Many to many relationship

Tags: php, orm, eloquent, many-to-many

I am using Eloquent ORM and I have a **Category** model that connects to a **Note** model by Many-to-Many relationship. I also have a **User** model that connects to the **Note** model by many to many relationship and to the **Category** model by one to many relationship.
The database structure is the following:
**notes**
id, title, content, created_at....

**categories**
id, title, description

**users**
id, first_name, last_name...

**note_user**
user_id, note_id, permission_id

**category_note**
category_id, note_id

**note_permissions**
permission_id, permissions

What I am trying to get:

1. All categories that contain notes that their IDs exist with a specific user ID in user_note table, and check the permission_id of that row.
2. Get all notes for a specific category that their IDs exist in user_note table with a certain user ID, and check permission_id of that row.

I wrote a method to check what permission a certain user has to a note (in **Note** model):

```
public function can($uid, $perm)
{
    $users = $this->users()->get();
    foreach ($users as $user) {
        if ($user->id == $uid) { // this user is shared
            $permId = $user->pivot->permission_id;
            $permissions = NotePerm::find($permId)->permissions;
            $perm = 'note.' . $perm;
            if (array_key_exists($perm, $permissions) && $permissions[ $perm ])
                return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

This is my idea to fetching all categories that contain notes that a certain user can see (meaning there is a row in user_note with his user ID and a note ID that belongs to this category) - this method is placed in **Category** model:

```
public function scopeWithNotesCan($query, $uid, $perm)
{
    return $query->whereHas('notes', function ($query) use ($uid, $perm) {
        $query->can($uid, $perm);
    });
}
```

And this is the call:

```
$categories->WithNotesCan($this->user->id, 'view');
```

Now, I am getting an error:

> Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::can()

How can I check each note with a custom method before fetching all notes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accomplished it by using multiple whereHas. In the **Category** model, added the following scope:

```
public function scopeForUser($query, $uid, $perm = 'view')
{
    return $query->whereHas('notes', function ($query) use ($uid, $perm) {
        $query->forUser($uid, $perm)->orWhere('private', '=', false);
    });
}
```

in the **Note** model, added the following scope:

```
public function scopeForUser($query, $uid, $perm = 'view')
{
    $permissions = NotePerm::findWhere($perm);
    return $query->whereHas('users', function ($query) use ($uid, $permissions) {
        $query->where('note_user.user_id', $uid)->whereIn('note_user.permission_id', $permissions)->orWhere('private', '=', false);
    });
}
```

The findWhere **NotePerm** method gets an array of all permissions the contain a certain permission string:

```
public function scopeFindWhere($query, $perm = 'view')
{
    $permissions = self::all();
    $perm = 'note.' . $perm;
    return $permissions->filter(function ($item) use ($perm) {
        return array_key_exists($perm, $item->permissions) && $item->permissions[ $perm ];
    })->lists('id')->toArray();
}
```

So to get all categories that are shared with a specific user (**$user** is the owner of the categories, not the specific user we are searching for):

```
$user->categories()->forUser($this->user->id, $perm);
```

To get all notes from a specific category that are shared with a specific user:

```
$user->categories()->forUser($this->user->id, $perm)->notes()->forUser($this->user->id, $perm);
```